# Add files/folders to a visual studio project using command line tool

Tags: file, visual-studio-2012, command-line, directory, addition

Is there a way to automatically add/include new files/folders into a Visual Studio project or to add/include them using a command line tool?

Answer (score 2):

You can access Visual Studio automation from VB Script. See the following sample .vbs file that can be run as an executable:

```
Dim dte
Dim project

Set dte = CreateObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0")
dte.Solution.Open("C:\Users\sv\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.sln")

For Each project In dte.Solution.Projects
 If project.Name = "ConsoleApplication1" Then
  project.ProjectItems.AddFromFile("C:\Users\sv\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\1.txt")
  project.Save(project.FullName)
 End If
Next

dte.Solution.Close()
```